# Pass Model as Argument in method

Tags: c#, generics, types, arguments

hi i want pass a json model to a function and doing something

```
public class myModel
{
public string url { get; set; }
public string assets_url { get; set; }
public string upload_url { get; set; }
}
```

```
public static string GetApi<T>(T Model)
 {
   return javaScript.Deserialize<Model>(reader.ReadToEnd());          
 }
```

usage

```
GetApi(myModel);
```

but i get error that model is variable and used like a type i tested (Type Model) but again not worked
so is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need something more like this `public static string GetApi<T>()
 => javaScript.Deserialize<T>(reader.ReadToEnd());` and then call it like this `GetApi<myModel>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a mess by confusing the concept of type with the concept of variable.

You want to call a generic method named `Deserialize<T>`.

In order to do so you need to specify a *generic type argument*, because your method has a *generic type parameter* (which is called T in my example definition of Deserialize method).

So you don't need a variable of a specific type, but rather you need the type itself and you must use the type as an argument to the generic method.

So let's suppose you have a class (a class is actually a type):

```
public class ApiContract 
{
   public string Foo { get; set; }
   public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine that you have a library exposing a generic method having this definition:

```
T Deserialize<T>(string json)
```

This is the way you should invoke the generic method `Deserialize`, from another generic method:

```
public void CallApiAndDoStuff<TApiResult>()
{
   // call a web api and get some json result

   TApiResult payload = deserializer.Deserialize<TAPiResult>(json);

   // do something with the api call payload
}
```

So, to summarize, you don't need a variable of type `TApiResult`, instead you need the type itself in order to pass it to the generic method invokation.

By the way, the compiler is telling this exact thing. The thing called `Model` in your code is actually a variable and you are pretending that he is a type, because you are passing it where the compiler would expect to find a type.

A variable has nothing to do with a type, that's a completely different concept. The only link between them is that given a variable it always has a type and that type can be declared explicitly (at the point of the variable declaration) or inferred implicitly by the compiler (when you use the `var` keyword at the point where you declare the variable).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string GetApi<T>(T Model) { return javaScript.Deserialize<T>(reader.ReadToEnd()); } try this change.
```

The deserialize method is a generic method, which means it needs a type parameter, and not a variable.